# Coordinate basis

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, tensors

A tensor article I read describes the old basis as x<sup>i</sup> and the new basis as y<sup>a</sup> and the coordinate transformation as y<sup>a</sup>(x<sup>a</sup>). It then says the functions are invertible so you can obtain the function x<sup>i</sup>(y<sup>a</sup>), and vice-versa.

Firstly, why is y<sup>a</sup>(x<sup>a</sup>) a function of x<sup>a</sup> whereas x<sup>i</sup>(x<sup>a</sup>) a function of x<sup>a</sup> and not x<sup>i</sup>?

Secondly, how does x<sup>i</sup>(y<sup>a</sup>) transform to y<sup>a</sup>(x<sup>a</sup>) and vice-versa?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Can you give a link to the "tensor article"?

Comment: Looks like sloppy superscripting. It should be $y^a(x^i)$ and $x^i(y^a)$. In less sloppy mathematical language, we have $y=f(x)$ and $x=g(y)$ with $g=f^{-1}$.

Comment: Thank-you all for comments on scripting as it's my first time. I did try finding information on how to and also tried copy-paste from Word. Maybe Stack Exchange could make it easier to find the help guides or even update their site to enable them (dare I say!). Thankyou ContraKinta for your excellent answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Consider two coordinate systems, relative to which the coordinates of a point $P$ are denoted by $(x^1,\dots,x^n)$ and $(y^1,\dots,y^n)$, respectively. These two n-tuples of real numbers are related to each other by transformation equations of the type
$$\begin{cases}y^1=f^1(x^1,\dots,x^n),\\ \\
\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots,\\\\
y^n=f^n(x^1,\dots,x^n)\end{cases}
$$
Where the functions $f^1,\dots,f^n$ are $n$ distinct functions of $n$ variables. In tensors algebra it is custom to denote the $n$-tuple $(x^1,\dots,x^n)$ by a single letter $x^h$, it being understood that all indices $j,h,k$ assume the values of $1$ to $n$. It is also custom to write the above system of $n$ transformation equations in the form of *a single relation*
$$y^j=f^j(x^h)\quad (j=1,\dots,n).$$
To economize the expression even further most authors usually just write
$$y^j=y^j(x^h)$$

Now lets assume that the functions $y^j(x^h)$ are of class $C^2$ in a region $G$ of some $n$-dimensional Euclidean space and that the functional determinant is nonvanishing on a subregion of $G$. Then the transformation possesses an inverse, expressed the form
$$x^h=x^h(y^j)$$
Where we again used the short form to represent the system of $n$ equations of which the right-hand sides are functions of the $n$ variables $y^j$ (compare this with the inverse function theorem).

For example, in polar coordinates we have

$$x^1=y^1\cos(y^2)\\
x^2=y^1\sin(y^2)$$
Where $x^1=x^1(y^1,y^2)$ and $x^2=x^2(y^1,y^2)$ or $x^h=x^h(y^j)$ for short.

Comment: Thyank-yo, much appreciated.